# token program onProgramAccountChange returns non-changed token accounts

Tags: spl-token-program, websocket

A subscription to onProgramAccountChange with the tokenProgram returns token accounts for which the data did not change. For example ey66efq9ZyxhwLjCbnX9D7Nj5hre9DNrNRyxigUwgJw last transaction is a year ago, but still it was returned by the socket. (For this account the closeAuthority and other attributes are 0/null so I assume they have not been changed.)

The code with arguments (as requested) looks like this:

```
solana_socket_connection.onProgramAccountChange(
    new PublicKey(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID),
    async (acc, context) => {
       code...
    }, "confirmed", [{ dataSize: 165 }, {memcmp: {offset: 32, bytes: "1BWutmTvYPwDtmw9abTkS4Ssr8no61spGAvW1X6NDix"}}]
);
```

An example of a response (as requested)
is

```
{
  accountId: {
    _bn: {
      negative: 0,
      words: [
        60989788,
        11544408,
        22922881,
        2676969,
        60614692,
        64456448,
        31305180,
        10195758,
        4316889,
        1767144,
        0,
      ],
      length: 10,
      red: null,
    },
  },
  accountInfo: {
    lamports: 2039280,
    data: new Uint8Array([174, 84, 1, 218, 163, 243, 252, 21, 247, 59, 14, 145, 183, 124, 181, 196, 230, 169, 10, 122, 149, 24, 107, 105, 160, 138, 28, 107, 13, 229, 169, 227, 0, 11, 227, 225, 235, 161, 122, 71, 63, 137, 176, 247, 232, 226, 73, 64, 242, 10, 235, 142, 188, 167, 26, 136, 253, 233, 93, 75, 131, 183, 26, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
    owner: {
      _bn: {
        negative: 0,
        words: [
          50266281,
          54354271,
          58266536,
          62225772,
          1881221,
          62578283,
          12457068,
          42356583,
          48355173,
          112509,
          0,
        ],
        length: 10,
        red: null,
      },
    },
    executable: false,
    rentEpoch: 361,
  },
}
```

When looking the accountId up in (f.e) solana explorer I see the last transaction is done over a month ago. I do not think the delegator/freezer or any other data has been changed, since they are all 0.

Comment: Could you provide the arguments that you're using and the response? It could be that the creation of the subscription returns its current state

Comment: I updated my post!

Comment: Hi, I've run into the same issue, did anyone end up finding a solution?